# How to totally reset a pc with multiple partitions?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub, reset

I would like to reset all my PC, including grub, windows boot manager, etc... (grub had caused a problem on my pc)

Information:

- I have 2 partitions which started in dual boot with Windows 8.1 and ubuntu 20.04 in dual boot.
- My PC does not start and does not recognize operating systems. (Nothing appears on the boot manager) [Here is a photo of the boot manager.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ixxff.jpg)
- I have an Ubuntu 20.04 live USB key.

(Of course, I was able to save my data before)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: there are many possible ways {google is your friend here} to do and it's depends on user preferences; narrow down your question to very specific problem

Comment: "Reset" is vague. Does blanking the drive count?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a new installation of Ubuntu would be fine...Just select the "Use entire disc" option when asked for it by the installer.